# Python Pandas Read SQL from IBM DB2 with non ASCII characters

Tags: python, sql, pandas, db2, ibm-cloud

I am using Pandas Read Sql in Python for executing sql-statements in IBM DB2 and saving the response in pandas dataframes. Now I am trying to execute a sql-statement containing a non ASCII character, a letter from the Swedish alphabet: 'Å' (others are Å, Ä and Ö) but I am getting this error:

"DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM DATA_CONFIG WHERE TAG_NAME='Å'': ibm_db_dbi::Error: Error occure during processing of statement"

This is my code:

```
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi
import pandas as pd

def sqlToFrame(sql): # Function for creating pandas dataframes from SQL-statements
    con = ibm_db.connect(connection_string, "", "")
    conn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(con)
    return pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

df = sqlToFrame("SELECT * FROM DATA_CONFIG WHERE TAG_NAME='Å'")
```

I've tried executing the statement in the IDE in the IBM DB2 interface which works perfectly fine. Therefore I am figuring that the problem might be connected to how I establish the connection/the DB2 driver pandas uses. I have tried finding a way to set an encoding but can't find anything. How can I solve this? I also know this is possible because another package that builds upon ibm_db accept these characters. The characters are a from the [ISO-8859-1 series](https://www.terena.org/activities/multiling/ml-docs/iso-8859.html#ISO-8859-1)

Comment: Which version of Python? Which bitness?  Which version of ibm_db, and ibm_db_dbi ?   Also what is the encoding of your target Db2 database?

Comment: Python2.7 with the latest version of those packages. The target DB2 database uses the default encoding @mao

Comment: Is it 32-bit python , or 64-bit python?  What operating-system runs the Db2-server?

Comment: Suggest you try with 64-bit Python 3.5 or higher. Seems ibm_db.c barfs when PyUnicode_FromObject() returns null or Py_None.

Comment: Can you carefully check your attempted SQL as there is no closing single quote after the character from posted error (NOT posted query)? I passed your special character to a DB2 connection with Python 3.5 and no error was raised.

Comment: My sql is fine, I have a clossing single quote, I also tested with an A instead of Å which works. But I think it could have to do with the Python version as some others have stated here. I’ll try with a newer Python version ASAP @Parfait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider parameterizing your query using the *params* argument of [`pandas.read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) and pass the accented character `'Å'` with `u''` prefix to bind value to the unquoted `?` placeholder in SQL query. Do note: params requires a sequence and so below passes a tuple of one item.

Unlike Python 2.x, all strings in Python 3.x are Unicode strings and so accented literals (non-ascii) do not need explicit decoding with `u'...'`. Hence, why I cannot reproduce your issue in my Python 3.5 running a DB2 SQL query with accented characters.

```
import pandas as pd
...

# Function for creating pandas dataframes from SQL-statements
def sqlToFrame(sql): 
    db = ibm_db.connect(connection_string, "", "")
    con = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(db)

    return pd.read_sql(sql, con, params = (u'Å',))


df = sqlToFrame("SELECT * FROM DATA_CONFIG WHERE TAG_NAME = ?")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually didn’t try your solution for 2.7. I thought ibm_db wasn’t supported in Python 3, so I upgraded my Python version instead which solved the problem. Thanks a lot for the help! @Parfait